# Setting up Navigation components for the first time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to use [Navigation components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.menus/com.example.menus.NavHostFragment}: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.menus.NavHostFragment@af68459 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

As you can see I am missing `OnFragmentInteractionListener` and in the top section of the fragment written:

> /**
>    * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
>    * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
>    * {@link RestaurantLogin.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
>    * to handle interaction events.
>    * Use the {@link RestaurantLogin#newInstance} factory method to
>    * create an instance of this fragment.
>    */

How do I implement `@link RestaurantLogin.OnFragmentInteractionListener` or `implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`.

I am using java (not Kotlin).

Comment: Are you actually using that auto-generated logic? If not, why not just delete it?

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean, can you explain alittle bit?. What to delete, where from.

Comment: Your `RestaurantLogin` has a bunch of logic in it, including a requirement for a `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. If you're not actually using that, you can just remove it.

Comment: Thank you @ianhanniballake, I removed everything except of `onCreateView` and now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that inside the fragment if you delete the following line the app stop crashing.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

change to

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

Not sure if this OK but it is working.